# Flavors, packages names and signing

Tags: android

I need some help understanding this after some hours of trying myself.

I have an app which I would like to release as a free app with ads, with the possibility to pay for add-free.

I have created those two versions with the help of flavors, so far so Good.

Now to my questions. Do those two flavors have to have different package names which also mean Im publishing two different apps to the store(each with its unique app-signing).

If this is not the case, how does signing and publishing for both releases simultainously work?

Thank you!

Comment: You could do this without using different package, implement something like register, if user is registered so disable admob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to publish 2 versions of your app (a free one and a pro one), you have to give different package names because package names are unique on the Play Store. 
To do that, here is an example :

```
productFlavors {
    free{

    }
    pro{
        applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
    }
}
```

The free version will be named `com.company.myapp`, and the pro one `com.company.myapp.pro`

Comment: Okey I see. Lets say a user chooses to pay for ad free version. Does the free version get overwritten or does the user end up with two apps? Perhaps not by default but can you get it to work  like this?

Comment: @Shoy user will end up with 2 apps, you can consider to create single app with in app purchase to disable ads

Comment: As @majov said, if the only difference between the two apps is ads, it's better to propose one app and use *In App Purchase* to disable ads